# AVfoundation Reverse Video

Tags: video, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avmutablecomposition, avassetreader

I tried to make video in reverse. While playing asset in AVPlayer i set the rate = -1 to make it work in reverse format. But how to export that video? I looked into docs. read about avassetwrite, sambuffers , compositions but didn't find any way to do this. Below links are refered by me

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Reverse video demo - 
https://github.com/mikaelhellqvist/ReverseClip

Above example to no longer works in IOS 8. and even it is not reversing audio. If anyone give me little hint on it then i can do further. I am stuck up here from last 5 days but didn't find any answer in docs.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi Amit, Any luck on above. I am also looking for the same thing. If any please let me know. Thanks

Comment: The same problem, giving upvote.

Comment: same issue here? Anyone get the answer ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193773/ios-reversing-video-file-mov/34403466#34403466](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193773/ios-reversing-video-file-mov/34403466#34403466 , maybe my answer can help you)

Comment: Any one got the solution for this........:)

Comment: Still no success, using avassetreader with high quality video app crashes even in iphone 7. I asked this question long time ago but still no help. Something like monopoly in video editing apps in ios, only few people can work & submit apps stors for video editing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to play around with AVAssetExportSession ( [MOV to Mp4 video conversion iPhone Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474517/mov-to-mp4-video-conversion-iphone-programmatically) ) - if it won't work, then your option will be to use AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter and reverse the frames inbetween (don't know about the sound though).